# Add a folder in Turnkeylinux - joomla

Tags: linux, joomla, turnkeylinux.org

I have downloaded turnkeylinux and installed in my machine. I can access the system via command line interface. Joomla is working fine.

Now I need to add an extra php file say "path.php" it will do some important database clean up and admin want to manually run it often.

My question is how to add my file ( path.php ) to the installed Joomla's root in Turnkeylinux ?
I only have remote command line access.

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't like custom PHP files. If the script you have is purely for database maintenance, then you could always try an extension such as [Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087). As well as database maintenance, it also provide security.

If you are set on using your custom PHP file, then you can add it to your Joomla site using [Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023)